# Neo4j web interface security

Tags: security, neo4j, debian

How secure is the Neo4j web interface? I have set a strong password, but as my web server is hosted and I can't access it locally, the port is open to the world. I am going to change the port numbers to something other than the default; is there anything else I can do to ensure the security of the Neo4j instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The password is stored salted and hashed on the server.

You can read more about security settings here:

http://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/security/checklist/

Comment: What I mean to say is, is it secure for me to leave the port open on a non-default port, or should I keep it closed where possible? And are there any other security precautions that I should take?